# Outsource java packages for reuse in other projects with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, package, reusability

I've got a project and within it, I developed a bunch of classes which are kept very abstract so I could use them in other projects. How should I outsource the package in a way so I can include it via gradle or by the IDE in the end?

Also the reusable packag-content is still in development so I want do work on it in parallel.

Can anybody tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` use a custom build to collect only the package that you want

```
task customBuild(type: Jar) {
    from ("src/main/java/abstract/"){
        into "abstract"
    }

    version = ""
    baseName = "myClasses"
}
```

it will build you a `jar` file inside `build/libs/YouJarName`

Now you can copy the jar to anywhere you want, and include it in another project in that way :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree (dir : "your/jar/location", includes: ["myJar.jar"])
}
```